# style label of checked checkbox, the label is nesteed in another div

Tags: html, css, checkbox, sass, label

So I'm trying to style the label of the checked checkbox, while nested in another div.
I can target all the labels, but not the label "connected" with that checkbox
I can't get it to work.

```
<input id="tab-button-1" class="hide-radio" type="radio" name="radio-tabs" value="1" checked>
<input id="tab-button-2" class="hide-radio" type="radio" name="radio-tabs" value="2">
<input id="tab-button-3" class="hide-radio" type="radio" name="radio-tabs" value="3">
<input id="tab-button-4" class="hide-radio" type="radio" name="radio-tabs" value="4">

<ul class="flex-list">
  <li>
    <label for="tab-button-1" class="tab-button">Tab name 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="tab-button-2" class="tab-button">Tab name 2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="tab-button-3" class="tab-button">Tab name 3</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="tab-button-4" class="tab-button">Tab name 4 !!</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<article class="tabs-content">

  <section id="content-1" class="tab-section">
    Lorem Ipsum Here for tab 1
  </section>

  <section id="content-2" class="tab-section">
    Lorem Ipsum Here for tab 2
  </section>

  <section id="content-3" class="tab-section">
    Lorem Ipsum Here for tab 3
  </section>

  <section id="content-4" class="tab-section">
    Lorem Ipsum Here for tab 4
  </section>

</article>
```

```
type here
```

Comment: `#tab-button-1:checked ~ .flex-list [for="tab-button-1"] { color: red }` selects just one.

Comment: but then i need to have this for everyone of the checkboxes not?, i plan to have more than four

Comment: Yes, unless you place the entire tab construction inside the `<li>` and rethink your code. Then something like `[id^="tab-button"]:checked + label {..}` and  `[id^="tab-button"]:checked + [id^="content"] {..}` could work. Check out this codepen: [Pure CSS Tabs](https://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/nRyxPz), which does just that... (btw, not by me). [Another, more elaborate example](https://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/pen/WNELRR), (dito).

Comment: Is there a way with jQuery, without changing the HTML structure?

Comment: Sure you can set a class to the label. Have you checked out react, qwik or anything else? This would be way easier than keeping track of all these checkboxes, resetting the classes and add them to the correct one.